# jQuery MultiSelect submit form on change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the excellent [jQuery MultiSelect](http://abeautifulsite.net/notebook/62) plugin.

The problem I have is that I would like to submit the form when the values have changed. 
Having all sorts of trouble getting this one working, does anyone have insight into how to achieve this?

Also open to alternative jQuery plugins/scripts if there are any that handle this nicely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try patching jQueryMultiSelect (Untested)

Line:34 --

```
multiSelect: function(o, callback ) {
```

Line:34 ++

```
multiSelect: function(o, callback, postback) {
```

Line 221: ++

```
if( postback ) postback($(this));
```

Full Codez

```
if(jQuery) (function($){

    $.extend($.fn, {
        multiSelect: function(o, callback, postback) {
            // Default options
            if( !o ) var o = {};
            if( o.selectAll == undefined ) o.selectAll = true;
            if( o.selectAllText == undefined ) o.selectAllText = "Select All";
            if( o.noneSelected == undefined ) o.noneSelected = 'Select options';
            if( o.oneOrMoreSelected == undefined ) o.oneOrMoreSelected = '% selected';

            // Initialize each multiSelect
            $(this).each( function() {
                var select = $(this);
                var html = '<input type="text" readonly="readonly" class="multiSelect" value="" style="cursor: default;" />';
                html += '<div class="multiSelectOptions" style="position: absolute; z-index: 99999; display: none;">';
                if( o.selectAll ) html += '<label class="selectAll"><input type="checkbox" class="selectAll" />' + o.selectAllText + '</label>';
                $(select).find('OPTION').each( function() {
                    if( $(this).val() != '' ) {
                        html += '<label><input type="checkbox" name="' + $(select).attr('name') + '" value="' + $(this).val() + '"';
                        if( $(this).attr('selected') ) html += ' checked="checked"';
                        html += ' />' + $(this).html() + '</label>';
                    }
                });
                html += '</div>';
                $(select).after(html);

                // Events
                $(select).next('.multiSelect').mouseover( function() {
                    $(this).addClass('hover');
                }).mouseout( function() {
                    $(this).removeClass('hover');
                }).click( function() {
                    // Show/hide on click
                    if( $(this).hasClass('active') ) {
                        $(this).multiSelectOptionsHide();
                    } else {
                        $(this).multiSelectOptionsShow();
                    }
                    return false;
                }).focus( function() {
                    // So it can be styled with CSS
                    $(this).addClass('focus');
                }).blur( function() {
                    // So it can be styled with CSS
                    $(this).removeClass('focus');
                });

                // Determine if Select All should be checked initially
                if( o.selectAll ) {
                    var sa = true;
                    $(select).next('.multiSelect').next('.multiSelectOptions').find('INPUT:checkbox').not('.selectAll').each( function() {
                        if( !$(this).attr('checked') ) sa = false;
                    });
                    if( sa ) $(select).next('.multiSelect').next('.multiSelectOptions').find('INPUT.selectAll').attr('checked', true).parent().addClass('checked');
                }

                // Handle Select All
                $(select).next('.multiSelect').next('.multiSelectOptions').find('INPUT.selectAll').click( function() {
                    if( $(this).attr('checked') == true ) $(this).parent().parent().find('INPUT:checkbox').attr('checked', true).parent().addClass('checked'); else $(this).parent().parent().find('INPUT:checkbox').attr('checked', false).parent().removeClass('checked');
                });

                // Handle checkboxes
                $(select).next('.multiSelect').next('.multiSelectOptions').find('INPUT:checkbox').click( function() {
                    $(this).parent().parent().multiSelectUpdateSelected(o);
                    $(this).parent().parent().find('LABEL').removeClass('checked').find('INPUT:checked').parent().addClass('checked');
                    $(this).parent().parent().prev('.multiSelect').focus();
                    if( !$(this).attr('checked') ) $(this).parent().parent().find('INPUT:checkbox.selectAll').attr('checked', false).parent().removeClass('checked');
                    if( callback ) callback($(this));
                });

                // Initial display
                $(select).next('.multiSelect').next('.multiSelectOptions').each( function() {
                    $(this).multiSelectUpdateSelected(o);
                    $(this).find('INPUT:checked').parent().addClass('checked');
                });

                // Handle hovers
                $(select).next('.multiSelect').next('.multiSelectOptions').find('LABEL').mouseover( function() {
                    $(this).parent().find('LABEL').removeClass('hover');
                    $(this).addClass('hover');
                }).mouseout( function() {
                    $(this).parent().find('LABEL').removeClass('hover');
                });

                // Keyboard
                $(select).next('.multiSelect').keydown( function(e) {
                    // Is dropdown visible?
                    if( $(this).next('.multiSelectOptions').is(':visible') ) {
                        // Dropdown is visible
                        // Tab
                        if( e.keyCode == 9 ) {
                            $(this).addClass('focus').trigger('click'); // esc, left, right - hide
                            $(this).focus().next(':input').focus();
                            return true;
                        }

                        // ESC, Left, Right
                        if( e.keyCode == 27 || e.keyCode == 37 || e.keyCode == 39 ) {
                            // Hide dropdown
                            $(this).addClass('focus').trigger('click');
                        }
                        // Down
                        if( e.keyCode == 40 ) {
                            if( !$(this).next('.multiSelectOptions').find('LABEL').hasClass('hover') ) {
                                // Default to first item
                                $(this).next('.multiSelectOptions').find('LABEL:first').addClass('hover');
                            } else {
                                // Move down, cycle to top if on bottom
                                $(this).next('.multiSelectOptions').find('LABEL.hover').removeClass('hover').next('LABEL').addClass('hover');
                                if( !$(this).next('.multiSelectOptions').find('LABEL').hasClass('hover') ) {
                                    $(this).next('.multiSelectOptions').find('LABEL:first').addClass('hover');
                                }
                            }
                            return false;
                        }
                        // Up
                        if( e.keyCode == 38 ) {
                            if( !$(this).next('.multiSelectOptions').find('LABEL').hasClass('hover') ) {
                                // Default to first item
                                $(this).next('.multiSelectOptions').find('LABEL:first').addClass('hover');
                            } else {
                                // Move up, cycle to bottom if on top
                                $(this).next('.multiSelectOptions').find('LABEL.hover').removeClass('hover').prev('LABEL').addClass('hover');
                                if( !$(this).next('.multiSelectOptions').find('LABEL').hasClass('hover') ) {
                                    $(this).next('.multiSelectOptions').find('LABEL:last').addClass('hover');
                                }
                            }
                            return false;
                        }
                        // Enter, Space
                        if( e.keyCode == 13 || e.keyCode == 32 ) {
                            // Select All
                            if( $(this).next('.multiSelectOptions').find('LABEL.hover INPUT:checkbox').hasClass('selectAll') ) {
                                if( $(this).next('.multiSelectOptions').find('LABEL.hover INPUT:checkbox').attr('checked') ) {
                                    // Uncheck all
                                    $(this).next('.multiSelectOptions').find('INPUT:checkbox').attr('checked', false).parent().removeClass('checked');
                                } else {
                                    // Check all
                                    $(this).next('.multiSelectOptions').find('INPUT:checkbox').attr('checked', true).parent().addClass('checked');
                                }
                                $(this).next('.multiSelectOptions').multiSelectUpdateSelected(o);
                                if( callback ) callback($(this));
                                return false;
                            }
                            // Other checkboxes
                            if( $(this).next('.multiSelectOptions').find('LABEL.hover INPUT:checkbox').attr('checked') ) {
                                // Uncheck
                                $(this).next('.multiSelectOptions').find('LABEL.hover INPUT:checkbox').attr('checked', false);
                                $(this).next('.multiSelectOptions').multiSelectUpdateSelected(o);
                                $(this).next('.multiSelectOptions').find('LABEL').removeClass('checked').find('INPUT:checked').parent().addClass('checked');
                                // Select all status can't be checked at this point
                                $(this).next('.multiSelectOptions').find('INPUT:checkbox.selectAll').attr('checked', false).parent().removeClass('checked');
                                if( callback ) callback($(this));
                            } else {
                                // Check
                                $(this).next('.multiSelectOptions').find('LABEL.hover INPUT:checkbox').attr('checked', true);
                                $(this).next('.multiSelectOptions').multiSelectUpdateSelected(o);
                                $(this).next('.multiSelectOptions').find('LABEL').removeClass('checked').find('INPUT:checked').parent().addClass('checked');
                                if( callback ) callback($(this));
                            }
                        }
                        return false;
                    } else {
                        // Dropdown is not visible
                        if( e.keyCode == 38 || e.keyCode == 40 || e.keyCode == 13 || e.keyCode == 32 ) { // down, enter, space - show
                            // Show dropdown
                            $(this).removeClass('focus').trigger('click');
                            $(this).next('.multiSelectOptions').find('LABEL:first').addClass('hover');
                            return false;
                        }
                        //  Tab key
                        if( e.keyCode == 9 ) {
                            // Shift focus to next INPUT element on page
                            $(this).focus().next(':input').focus();
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                    // Prevent enter key from submitting form
                    if( e.keyCode == 13 ) return false;
                });

                // Eliminate the original form element
                $(select).remove();
            });

        },

        // Hide the dropdown
        multiSelectOptionsHide: function() {
            $(this).removeClass('active').next('.multiSelectOptions').hide();
            if( postback ) postback($(this));
        },

        // Show the dropdown
        multiSelectOptionsShow: function() {
            // Hide any open option boxes
            $('.multiSelect').multiSelectOptionsHide();
            $(this).next('.multiSelectOptions').find('LABEL').removeClass('hover');
            $(this).addClass('active').next('.multiSelectOptions').show();

            // Position it
            var offset = $(this).offset();
            $(this).next('.multiSelectOptions').css({ top:  offset.top + $(this).outerHeight() + 'px' });
            $(this).next('.multiSelectOptions').css({ left: offset.left + 'px' });

            // Disappear on hover out
            multiSelectCurrent = $(this);
            var timer = '';
            $(this).next('.multiSelectOptions').hover( function() {
                clearTimeout(timer);
            }, function() {
                timer = setTimeout('$(multiSelectCurrent).multiSelectOptionsHide(); $(multiSelectCurrent).unbind("hover");', 250);
            });

        },

        // Update the textbox with the total number of selected items
        multiSelectUpdateSelected: function(o) {
            var i = 0, s = '';
            $(this).find('INPUT:checkbox:checked').not('.selectAll').each( function() {
                i++;
            })
            if( i == 0 ) {
                $(this).prev('INPUT.multiSelect').val( o.noneSelected );
            } else {
                if( o.oneOrMoreSelected == '*' ) {
                    var display = '';
                    $(this).find('INPUT:checkbox:checked').each( function() {
                        if( $(this).parent().text() != o.selectAllText ) display = display + $(this).parent().text() + ', ';
                    });
                    display = display.substr(0, display.length - 2);
                    $(this).prev('INPUT.multiSelect').val( display );
                } else {
                    $(this).prev('INPUT.multiSelect').val( o.oneOrMoreSelected.replace('%', i) );
                }
            }
        }

    });

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Found a very dodgy hack based on this solution that is too dodgy to post (involving global_variables tied to my specific requirements), but is graced by the actual value of working correctly. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

K, if running in to problems because you are trying to get the value for a ASP.NET postback you can try this. It is a bit of a hack but change line in the `renderOption` function:

```
var html = '<label><input type="checkbox" name="' + id + '[]" value="' + option.value + '"';
```

to:

```
var html = '<label><input type="checkbox" name="' + id.replace(/_/g,"$") + '" value="' + option.value + '"';
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried attaching it directly to the multiselect callback?

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("#control_id").multiSelect(options, function() {
        $('#myFormId').submit();
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes, however the callback is called each time one of the options is checked/unchecked, as opposed to the hide/finish event. So the page will submit in the middle of the selection process.

Answer (score 0):

First I did save the selected item in an hiddenfield and after post back I assigned these checked items in an comma separated format. I wrote a `document.ready()` function like the one below to check the value of the selected to the dropdownlist:

```
var Quali = document.getElementById('<%=hdCommaList.ClientID%>').value; 
var qualiList = Quali.split(',');
for (var dx = 0; dx < qualiList.length; dx++) {
    if (!(qualiList[dx] == '')) {
        $('input[type="checkbox"][value="' + qualiList[dx] + '"]').attr('checked', true).trigger('click').attr('checked', true);
    }
}
```